# Cause useSWR to refetch on page mount even if key is cached in Next.js

Tags: next.js, swr

So I'm using the useSWR hook to fetch data from my api endpoints. I'm aware that it uses the api routes as the key to cache the data.

The problem is, I am using an api route on 2 pages (let's call them Page1 and Page2), just with different queries. So whenever I visit Page1 first, if I then navigate to page 2, it shows the cached version of page 1 and vice versa.

I tried using the mutate function on both pages and all it does is to first show the cached version before revalidating. Which isn't ideal. What I want is on page mount, the correct data should show.

I also tried setting the revalidateOnMount flag to true in the SWRConfig options in the _app.js like so:

```
...
   <SWRConfig value={{ revalidateOnMount: true}}>
      ...
    </SWRConfig>
...
```

Doesn't work.

I should mention that I do have initialData coming from getStaticProps functions on both pages as well.

Would appreciate any bit of help. Been stuck on this for quite some time.

Comment: Have you considered passing an array as the `key` param to `useSWR`, like in the [multiple arguments scenario](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments#multiple-arguments)? In this case the key will be a combination of the values in the array.

Comment: @juliomalves thank you very much. Don't know how I've skipped over that. Very much appreciated. It worked.

Comment: By the way, how do I mark your comment as the right answer? Or it has to be in an actual answer?

Comment: It has to be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @juliomalves pointed out above, you can pass [multiple arguments](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments#multiple-arguments) to the hook and they both become the key to the cached data.